# Получить id таксономии 1 уровня в зависимости от текущей WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть структура категорий woocommerce:

1. Мужское
2. Мужское > Шапки
3. Мужское > Шапки > Вязаные
4. Мужское > Шапки > Резиновые
5. Женские
6. Женские > Шапки
7. Женские > Шапки > Вязаные
8. Женские > Шапки > Резиновые

Как получить ID категории "Женские", когда я нахожусь в категории "Женские > Шапки > Резиновые"?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Есть специальная функция для получения всех id родительский категорий `get_ancestors`. ID будут отсортированны от ближнего уровня к самому последнему. Затем через `get_terms` вы можете получить все нужные вам термины.

```
$current_term    = get_queried_object();
$parent_term_ids = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
$parent_terms    = get_terms(
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'include'  => $parent_term_ids,
        'orderby'  => 'include',
    ]
);
var_dump( $parent_terms );
```

Comment: Я таким образом получаю все родительские категории. А как получить только ту, которая является родительской для текущей?

Comment: $parent_term = get_term( $current_term->parent );

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как применить эту переменную? Что-то не могу сообразить..

Comment: $current_term    = get_queried_object();